# What happens if you collide 2 alpha particles?

Tags: radiation

What happens if you collide 2 alpha particles?

Alpha particles as far as I know are particles of 2 neutrons and 2 protons.

Does anyone know what happens if 2  such particles collide?

Comment: Are you asking about Rutherford scattering, or possible nuclear reactions, or what?

Comment: Possible nuclear reactions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When looking for nuclear reactions, the place to go is the Evaluated and Compiled Nuclear Structure Data File repository of your choice. I use [the one at Brookhaven](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/). Enter in the compound nucleus (8Be) and see what the options are. You will find just two options.

The first one is listed as "4HE(A,G)" - this is an $\alpha$-$\alpha$ collision resulting in production of a gamma ray from excited nuclear states of the compound 8Be nucleus. The second one is "4HE(A,A)" which is  $\alpha$ scattering. Both are used to explore properties of the compound nucleus.

The 8Be nucleus is extremely unstable with respect to falling apart into 2 $\alpha$ particles, with a ground-state lifetime of less than $10^{-16}$ seconds. From a nuclear history perspective, this is well known, since the first human-controlled cross-section measurement was Cockroft and Walton performing the 7Li(p,$\alpha$)$\alpha$ reaction on their newly invented ion accelerator.

Comment: In other words, they stick together for around $10^{-16}$ seconds and then just split apart again.

Comment: @GuyInchbald - that is best case where the compound nucleus is formed in the ground state.

Comment: OK, looking forward to the rest of the answer, then.

Comment: @GuyInchbald - higher energy states of the 8Be nucleus decay faster, that’s all. There is no ‘rest’ of the answer. I could perhaps dig up estimates of said decay times but it doesn’t change the answer - 8Be as a compound nucleus falls apart and may yield a gamma in the process. That is it for your nuclear reaction options.

Comment: If another alpha manages to collide with the Be-8 before it falls apart, you have the [triple-alpha process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process). Note helium burning requires a much higher temperature than the p-p chain of hydrogen fusion: 100 Mk vs 4 Mk (megakelvin).

Comment: @PM2Ring - indeed, but that reaction didn’t seem what the OP asked for...